# How can I force order of fetch result processing in my React app?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, components, fetch

I'm using React 16.13.0.  I want to create a simple search component -- a single text box that as you type displays results.  I have created the following component ...

```
export default class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchTerm: "",
            setSearchTerm: "",
            searchResults: [],
            setSearchResults: []
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const query = event.target.value;
        if ( ! query ) {
            this.setState({ searchTerm: query, searchResults: [] } );
        } else {
            this.setState({ searchTerm: query, loading: true }, () => {
                this.doSearch(query);
            });
        }
    }

    doSearch = ( query ) => {
        console.log("dosearch:" + query);
        const searchUrl = '/coops/?contains=' + encodeURIComponent(query);
        fetch(searchUrl,{
            method: "GET"
        }).then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            console.log("query:" + query);
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({
                searchResults: data,
                loading: false,
            });
        });
    };


    renderSearchResults = () => {
        const {searchResults} = this.state;
        if (searchResults && searchResults.length) {
            return (
                <div className="results-container">
                    <div>Results</div>
                    <ul>
                        {searchResults.map(item => (
                        <li className="result-items" key={item.id} value={item.name}>{item.name}</li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="searchForm">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    value={this.state.searchTerm}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                { this.renderSearchResults() }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

The issue is that if I type too fast, the fetch requests do not necessarily complete in the order they are sent out.  For exmple, if my term is "south," the fetch corresponding to having typed "sou" may complete after I've fully typed "south," causing the results to be displayed incorrectly.  How do I account for this and force my results to be displayed corresponding to the inputs typed?

Comment: What you can do, if you can, is to send the `searchTerm` in the reponse of you request. So when you get a new response you check if the sended `searchTerm` is the actual one in the input. Most search API follow this principe to send the query back.

Comment: You know, that's a really good idea.  In fact, I don't even think I have to put it in the response -- I would know in the ".then(data => {" block what the query is and what the state's searchTerm is and should be able to compare it there.

Comment: How do know what the query is?

Comment: It is getting passed to my function --, "doSearch = ( query )"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **onKeyUp={}** this means that when user finished typing their search query only there you will start making the request.

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Search" 
    value={this.state.searchTerm} 
    onKeyUp={this.handleChange} 
/>
```

Comment: Fetch calls are asynchrone so what if the response of `sou` take more time that the response of `south`? The response of `south` will be show first but then finally the response of `sou` comes too and the state is updated. Result -> the input show the word `south` but the response of `sou` is displayed. In this case the use of `onKeyUp` will not fix the error